# Application of Chinese Remainder Theorem in a task

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

Every second I get a remainder $r_i$ by division x $\in \{1, 2, ..., 100\}$ by $a_i$. All $a_i$ are unique, but $a_i$ can be equal to 1. How many pairs of $a_i$ and $r_i$ I need to guess x? This problem related to chinese remainder theorem, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Is there some sort of limit on the value of $x$? Otherwise, there is no limit on many divisions you might need to do. However, in general, if the $a_i$ are the smallest prime numbers, I believe you'll usually just need to use the primes up the next larger primorial of $x$, but I haven't done the calculations to confirm this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I forgot to mention it. x is from 1 to 100